# Google Place API error when I used in cpp project or with curl command

Tags: google-places-api

Recently I started working with Google Place API. I have created one server key for my current project. As I have to use Place API so I turned it on in Service page.

When I am using the following URL in my browser, I get the desired output in the browser.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY`

But if I use the URL above  in my current C++ project or with the curl command on ubuntu terminal, I get the following error.

```
{
   "error_message" : "An internal error was found for this API project.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

What should I do to correct this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

if you used the uri

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY

you sending a request to google, logging for the account with the key 'MY_API_KEY'

i guess you need to register for a [key](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#UsingKeys) and use it as parameter value

Comment: I have used the generated Service API key instead of MY_API_KEY and have registered for PLACE API in service pane and still am getting the same error while using with curl command in Ubuntu machine . If I use the above URL in my ubuntu browser, I am getting the desired output with the above pasted URL.